# Question about absolute continuous functions (preservation of null sets)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to prove that a function $ f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R} $ is absolutely continuous iff $ \mu(A) = 0 \implies \mu( f(A)) = 0$ for all such $A \subseteq [a,b]$. I'm quite stuck. I'm trying to work from the definition to prove that if f is a.c. then the condition holds, but I am stuck since I can't seem to come up with an appropriate cover for $ f(A)$. I saw on another site that it follows from the fact that f being a.c. is equivalent to $f(x) = f(a) + \int_0^x \phi(t)dt$ where $\phi = f'$. but I can't see how it works. Could anyone provide help? Many thanks.

Comment: The answer below of Moishe Cohen addresses this, but it's false, as a trivial counterexample, consider a step function: it has the property that $\mu(A) = 0 \implies \mu( f(A)) = 0$ (it's image is only two points in fact) but is not even continuous, let alone absolutely continuous.

Answer (score 4):

One direct way of dealing with this is using the fact that sets of measure 0 in the line have outer measure 0, which means that given any $\delta$, we can cover the set with open intervals whose total length is less than $\delta$. The definition of absolute continuity then shows that we can make the image have outer measure less than any $\epsilon>0$, so it must have measure 0.

Comment: Do we not still have to reduce the cover to a finite, disjoint one to apply the property of absolute continuity? Also, how do we get from a cover of $A$ by intervals to a corresponding cover of $f(A)$. If $ \{ (a_i, b_i) \}_i $ cover A then will $ \{ (f(a_i), f(b_i)) \}_i $ cover the image? I think no, and so we have to modify things a bit. That was the trouble I had.

Comment: @kolmogorov Any open cover has a finite subcover - that is a property of the compactness of your interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: The closed intervals of the image cover by the intermediate value theorem, and they are as close in size to the open intervals as you can desire.

Comment: @RayYang we only have a cover of the measurable set $A$, not the interval $[a,b]$. So how do we cut down our cover of $A$ in order to apply the definition of absolute continuity? We can certainly assume that we have a covering with disjoint, open intervals, but I am still having trouble cutting it down to a finite cover.

Comment: @BrianRushton of course. The intermediate value theorem works and so the intervals we get will cover the image.

Comment: @kolmogorov Of course, my apologies, I wasn't reading clearly enough. However, I don't think the finiteness actually matters in the definition. Here's my thinking: suppose you have your usual $(\epsilon, \delta)$ pair, and suppose you have a countably infinite collection of intervals $I_k = (x_k,y_k)$ such that $\sum |I_k| < \delta$. Then what is $\sum |f(y_k)-f(x_k)|$? Since every partial sum of this series is bounded by $\epsilon$, then the whole series must be as well. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but it is good to set things straight:

What you are trying to prove is simply false. The correct result is

**Banach–Zaretskii theorem**. Suppose that $f: [a,b]\to {\mathbb R}$ is a continuous function. Then $f$ is absolutely continuous if and only if it has Luzin property N (sends measure zero sets to measure zero sets) and, *in addition*, has bounded variation.

Dropping the bounded variation property can result in functions which are not absolutely continuous, see item 8 [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Luzin-N-property).